# jQuery doesn't run after including it to a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Something strange happening with my Chrome's console! The task is to add jQuery lib to a page and then do some stuff using it (jQuery). I wrote some code:

```
    //First part   
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    //Second part 
    $('a[href="?tab=MM"]').text('asdasdasd');
```

When I paste whole code to console - I get `TypeError: Property 'text' of object [object HTMLAnchorElement] is not a function`

**BUT!** When I paste separately first part(which creates script-tag) and then second (jQuery expression) I get normal expected result!

Can anyone explain what I do wrong? And what should I do to make script in a **right way**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run the code line by line, the browser has time to download and execute the JavaScript in the script element you are appending.

When you include it in the page, the "Second part" is executed as soon as the script element is added to the DOM but the JS that adds to the page won't be executed until the current script is finished.

This is why jQuery's `getScript` method takes a callback function.

You can get a similar effect but wrapping your "second part" in a function and using that as a load event listener on the script element. I don't know what browser support for that is like though.

Comment: @samosfator — See the last paragraph of my answer, or read the source code to jQuery's `getScript` method.